# require a file that's not a module

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have some js files that contains plain javascript, but they are not modules, how can I import those scripts on my main file?

foo.js

```
function f1(){
   return;
}
function f2(){
   return;
}
```

main.js

```
require('./foo.js'); //import inline

console.log('hello world!');

f1();
```

Bundle expected

```
/******/
/******/ //webpack stuff
(function(){

    function f1(){
       return;
    }
    function f2(){
       return;
    }

    console.log('hello world!');

    f1();
})();
```

Comment: Does your code work? If not, what error are you receiving?

Comment: if your intent is to register the functions for use globally, you can do like so in foo.js: `global.f1 = f1; global.f2 = f2;` however it is preferable to just export the functions

Comment: thats not how webpack works.. it does not pollute global namespace, it create a chunk/module-id for each file name, which is later used when you require it, so its just reuqire-id and not full code import

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using webpack, you can use the [exports](https://github.com/webpack/exports-loader) loader:

```
var foo = require("exports?f1,f2!./foo.js");
foo.f1();
foo.f2();
```

The loader will inject `exports` assignments.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a grunt task called [grunt-import](https://github.com/marcinrosinski/grunt-import). It does exactly what I want, and then I run the webpack after.

**foo.js**

```
function f1(){
   return;
}
function f2(){
   return;
}
```

**main.js**

```
@import "foo.js"; //import inline

console.log('hello world!');

f1();
```

Ouput:

> ```
> function f1(){
>    return;
> }
> function f2(){
>    return;
> }
>
> console.log('hello world!');
>
> f1();
> ```

---

### Grunt task boilerplate

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        import: {
            dist: {
                src: 'src/hello/main.js',
                dest: 'dist/main.js',
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-import');

};
```

Then run `grunt import` on the terminal.